# ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed() is not being called on redeploy on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, amazon-s3, tomcat8

Yes it's configured in `web.xml`. It's called when I do a server restart, that is shutdown and startup, however when I do a **REDEPLOY** only the `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` is called. I need to call `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()` to free up certain resources such as the AmazonS3 client which has some cleanup to do.

Comment: This listener should always be called. Tomcat version? How are you determining that the `contextDestroyed` is (not) being called?

Comment: It's not called on a redeploy, only on a restart. You can just put a System.out.println. You can clearly see the init called but not the destroy. And Tomcat 8.25

Comment: No such Tomcat version. Where are you looking for the `System.out.println` output? It can be put into `catalina.out` or possibly in the application's log file (if `swallowOutput=true` on the context). Remember that `System.out` is buffered.

Comment: did you ever solve this?